# Binary classifier of words in list

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification

I have extracted text using OCR from a number of stylized documents in Swedish. Now I want formalize the data and extract city names. Due to the OCR working imperfectly, the names are sometimes spelled wrong and shows up at semi-random positions in the text. Therefore regex does not work.

Is it a good procedure/possible to transform the text into bags of words and train an algorithm to binary categorize words as city vs not city?

Consider example data set:

```
Col1                                          Col2
['Hi', 'there', 'Haag']                      ['Haag']
[‘Paris, ‘is’, ‘better’, ‘than’, ‘Osloe]     [‘Paris’, ‘Oslo’]
['My', 'hometown', 'is', 'New York']         ['New York']
...
```

I want to use Col1 as X variable and Col2 as Y variable. Is this a good procedure or should I use another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way of dealing with spelling mistakes is to first collect your vocabulary (all words in the corpus) and to then select candidate OCR mistakes by their individual term frequencies (assuming that mistakes like `"Osloe"` are rare). In a second step you could use [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) to link candidate spelling mistakes to their correct word forms.

To extract cities you could, for example, take a look at [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities)'s pretrained models for named entity recognition.

Collocations like `"New York"` you could identify by contrasting the frequency of the terms to go together in sequence vs the individual term frequencies (depending on your corpus `"York"` might often go together with `"New"` much more often than one would assume under a hypothesis of the occurrence of `"New"` and `"York"` being independent).

Comment: I should have added that the documents are in Swedish. I don't think Spacy support Swedish, https://spacy.io/usage/models.

Comment: you might be able to find similar taggers for swedish. however, if you have to roll your own, i am not sure whether your proposed BOW approach will work well.

Following the distributional hypothesis, entities like locations will be used in similar contexts (i.e. surrounded by similar words). So what you could do is use a sequence model or word embedding that takes the context into account.

Alternatively, you might want to look into morphological features: You could generate a character-ngram and learn a binary function that tells you whether a word itself is a city/location.